# How to clone an element and use it in many places by using Javascript and the Dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a link-node. I want to be able to clone it and use the copy multiple times in different places. Can I do that? 
Here is my javascript-code:

```
    var lank = document.createElement("a"); //Skapa en länk som heter lank
lank.setAttribute("class" , "visa");
lank.setAttribute("href" , "#");
var lankTN = document.createTextNode("Läs mer"); // Skapa en textnod som heter lankTN
lank.appendChild(lankTN); //Sätt in lankTN i lank

//Gömma texterna då sidan laddas och placera in länkar med texten Läs mer
window.onload = function uppstart(){
var texterna = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
for (var i = 0; i<texterna.length; i++){
texterna[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].appendChild(lank);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) to clone a node. So if `lank` is what you want to clone:

```
var clone = lank.cloneNode(true);
```

The flag is for whether to clone its children. Usually you want to.

I'm guessing you want to do it in this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].appendChild(lank);
```

...which looks like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].appendChild(lank.cloneNode(true));
```

---

Side note: You don't have to use `setAttribute` to set the class and href, you can use the reflected properties:

```
lank.className = "visa";
lank.href = "#";
```

Here are [more DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) that may be of interest, and the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) now includes some DOM stuff as well.

Comment: You also do not need to create a text node. You can just use `lank.innerHTML = 'text'`.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Using a text node prevents the text being treated as HTML. Of course, with `"Läs mer"`, it doesn't matter, there are no HTML entities or tags in there...